# Flex 4 component on top of TitleWindow

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have Flex `s:Group` with some ui elements and I want it to be always (!) on top of any component inside my app, including `s:TitleWindow` (dialog).
How can I achieve it with Flex 4?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add you top component in systemManager.rawChildren after application creationComplete event. See down:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               creationComplete="application_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.UIComponent;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.managers.PopUpManager;

            protected function application_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                panel.width = width;
                panel.height = 300;
                systemManager.rawChildren.addChild(panel);
            }

            protected function addPopup():void
            {
                PopUpManager.addPopUp(titleWin, this, true);
                PopUpManager.centerPopUp(titleWin);
            }

            protected function button_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                addPopup();
            }

            protected function titleWin_closeHandler(evt:CloseEvent):void 
            {
                PopUpManager.removePopUp(evt.currentTarget as UIComponent);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Panel id="panel" backgroundColor="0x00ff00" alpha="0.9" title="Panel">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="50" horizontalAlign="left" verticalAlign="middle" />
            </s:layout>
            <s:Button id="btn" width="200" height="100" label="create popup" 
                      click="button_clickHandler(event)" /> 
        </s:Panel>

        <s:TitleWindow id="titleWin"
                       title="Spark TitleWindow"
                       close="titleWin_closeHandler(event);"
                       width="300">
            <s:layout>
                <s:VerticalLayout paddingLeft="10" paddingRight="10"
                                  paddingTop="10" paddingBottom="10" />
            </s:layout>
            <s:Label text="Popup window"
                     fontSize="24"
                     width="100%"/>
        </s:TitleWindow>
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `mx.managers.PopUpManager` class. It provides a simple interface to handle displaying content above any other.

You can write your own interface that encapsulates the `PopUpManager` interface to give you a chance to bring all your "always-on-top" components on top again, even when you add another popup that should appear behind.

Simple example:

```
public final class AlwaysOnTopPopUpManager {

    private static var alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects:Array;

    public static function addAlwaysOnTopObject(displayObject:IFlexDisplayObject):void
    {
        alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects = alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects || [];

        if (alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects.indexOf(displayObject) == -1)
        {
            alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects.push(displayObject);
            arrange();
        }
    }


    public static function removeAlwaysOnTopObject(displayObject:IFlexDisplayObject):void
    {
        if (alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects)
        {
            var index:int = alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects.indexOf(displayObject);

            if (index != -1)
            {
                alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    }


    // uses the same interface as mx.managers.PopUpManager
    public static function addPopUp(window:IFlexDisplayObject, parent:DisplayObject, modal:Boolean = false, childList:String = null, moduleFactory:IFlexModuleFactory = null):void
    {
        mx.managers.PopUpManager.addPopUp(window, parent, modal, childList, moduleFactory);
        arrange();
    }


    private static function arrange():void
    {
        for each (var popup:IFlexDisplayObject in alwaysOnTopDisplayObjects)
        {
            mx.managers.PopUpManager.bringToFront(popup);
        }
    }
```

The class holds a list of objects to appear above any other content. Each time an object is added to that list or to the popups the `arrange()` method is called and bring all your registered objects to front again.

Answer (score 0):

If all your elements are in the same MXML file, you simply have to put your `s:Group` element at the bottom of the file as the last element of it.

If your views are wired more dynamically, then you can force its index with something like this:

```
var topIndex:int = myParentView.numChildren - 1;
myParentView.setChildIndex(myGroupElement, topIndex);
```

Where `myGroupElement` if the reference to your `s:Group` or its ID.

`myGroupElement` must already be a child of `myParentView` when this code is executed.

If your `s:Group` element is only displayed occasionally, you might be interested in `Popup`s.

Comment: The problem is that I need my `s:Group` to be over dialog (TitleWindow), and it doesn't work neither with `UIComponent. setChildIndex`, nor with `UIComponent.depth`.

Comment: Can you then give us a code sample? I have no idea where are both of the cited elements in your application.

Comment: @IvanZamylin the problem is you post two sentences and expect people to guess at an answer. Frankly, this answer was an appropriate guess. We can't help you unless you're willing to show the code that you're using. By the way, I have an African swallow, can you tell me it's unladen airspeed?